# VBA: Copy & Paste data from source workbook to destination worksheet If their Cell "A1" value is equal to each others

Tags: excel, vba

-I have 2 workbooks now, one is the source, another one is the destination.

-They have the same format, but only the source file contains data

-Both workbooks have the same TABs (But the Tabs are variables, For example, Tab A, B, C are created this time, but next time they might be Tab C, D, E)

- I would like to have something like this:

I have already set wb1 (Source) & wb2 (Destination) As those 2 workbooks

```
Dim ws As worksheet
 If wb1.ws.Name = wb2.ws.Name Then
```

Copy & paste the same Tab info. (Range A1 to last row) from wb1 to wb2

- But somehow the code is not supported by VBA. What is the correct code that I can set

Thanks!

```
Sub Macro1()

' Copy & paste from workbook to workbook

Dim Wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set Wb1 = Application.Workbooks("Test Template")
Dim Wb2 As Excel.Workbook
Set Wb2 = Application.Workbooks("Hy.xlsm")

Set ws1 = Wb1.Worksheets
Set ws2 = Wb2.Worksheets

If ws1.Name = ws2.Name Then
    MsgBox "True"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I can provide the VBA I've done if needed

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question with what you have so far, thanks.

Comment: If the tab names are the same, then just loop through all the worksheets in `wb1` and refer to the worksheet in `wb2` by the worksheet name from `wb1`.

Comment: When you set `ws` it gets the workbook attached and as such you cannot do `wb1.ws.Name` as that will refer to two workbooks.

Comment: Thanks you guys, @BigBen How can I  loop through all the worksheets in wb1 and refer to the worksheet in wb2 by the worksheet name from wb1?  Because those Tab names are various in time to time, I cannot type in a fix Tab name in the VBA code

Answer (score 0):

If the tab names are the same, then loop through the worksheets in `Wb1` and use each worksheet name to refer to the corresponding worksheet in `Wb2`, something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Set Wb1 = Workbooks("Test Template")
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook
    Set Wb2 = Workbooks("Hy.xlsm")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Wb1.Worksheets
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Set ws2 = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws2 = Wb2.Worksheets(ws.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
            ' Do your copy here.
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```